# Using dynamic CSS variables broke some of Bootstrap themes

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass

Using Angular / Bootstrap, I changed CSS variables at runtime, using this line of code :

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${property.name}`, property.value);
```

*for reference, i used this example to deal with bootstrap SCSS imports : https://blog.wick.technology/runtime-dynamic-bootstrap-theme/*

It does work, but some of Bootstrap' styles in bootstrap are broken :
[image]

I guess that's because the calc function does not support my dynamic vars :

```
.btn-primary {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, calc(-100 * calc(var(--primary-l) - 58.59375%)), 1);
    background-color: var(--primary);
    border-color: var(--primary);
}
```

Is there any way that I can fix this behaviour ? Can I overload a new definition of **btn-primary** ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already solved your problem or not, but I had the same problem and I feel like I solved it.

I basically decided to create the variables `"${variable}-h",${variable}-s", ${variable}-l"`, which are calculated at runtime when defining the variable, converting the `RGB` color to the different `HSL` color components.